# Remove characters in ListBox after read

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I am developing a tiny app and am having a little problem. I have a file `C:\file.txt` that contains the following:

```
1;name;category1    
2;name2;category2    
n;namen;categoryn
```

I'm adding lines from this file to a `ListBox` with:

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\file.txt")
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
```

In this `ListBox`, I can see the lines from the file, but I would like to see something like this:

```
1     name     category1
2     name     category2
n     namen    categoryn
```

Is that possible, and if so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\file.txt")

For i = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
    lines(i) = lines(i).Replace(";", vbTab)
Next

ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
```

edit: with formatting

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\file.txt")
For i = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim parts() As String = lines(i).Split(";")
    lines(i) = String.Format("{0,-10}{1,-15}{2,-10}", parts(0), parts(1), parts(2))
Next
```

be sure to use a monospace font like Consolas

Comment: Yeah! you got it!...but...now it looks out of order like this:
    
    1     nameas asas    4
    2     name  asasaa   5
    n     na men    3

Comment: is your problem that they dont stand perfectly underneath each other? you might wanna use a formatting in that case(i'll edit the answer that way). if not please update your question.